# Please explain move constructors and assignement logic flow

Tags: c++, move, move-semantics, move-constructor

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Move {
private:
    int* data;
public:
    Move(int d) {
        data = new int;
        *data = d;

        std::cout << "Constructor is called for " << d << std::endl;
    }

    Move(const Move& source) : Move{*source.data} {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor is called - " << "Deep copy for " << *source.data << std::endl;
    }

    Move(Move&& source) noexcept : data{ source.data } {
        std::cout << "Move constructor for " << *source.data << std::endl;
        source.data = nullptr;
    }

    ~Move() {
        if (data != nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Destructor is called for " << *data << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Destructor is called for " << "nullptr" << std::endl;
        }

        delete data;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Move> vec;

    vec.push_back(Move{ 10 });
    vec.push_back(Move{ 20 });

    return 0;
}
```

`

found this code example on the net, when i compile with one object inside vector one message from constructor one from move constructor and two messages from destructor are called, but when i compile with two objects two messages from constructor three messages from move constructor and five from destructor.

This really confuses me what happens. Could you please explain in details if possible.

Comment: Vectors can *reallocate* on insertion, moving all the existing elements into new memory location.

Comment: doest it mean move constructor called many times when you push_back an object,  doesn't it affect performance?

Comment: The way vector works is that it allocates memory for X elements. As long as size is less than X, insertion at the back is very cheap - no allocation, you just move (or emplace) the element directly in the memory. But if you want to insert more than X, the vector has to allocate bigger chunk of memory and move all existing elements into that new memory. It's a trade-off, but it's usually worth it. You get contiguous memory and (usually) very cheap insertion at back at the price that it may have to reallocate.

Comment: If you know in advance how many elements you are going to `push_back`/`emplace_back`, you can call [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to allocate enough memory for this many elements to avoid reallocations.

Comment: Thanks for explaining about vectors, but my question is still about constructors and their behavior not vectors.

Comment: But this has everything to do with vectors. You get one constructor call for `Move{ 10 }`, then one to move-construct it into vector. Then, you get constructor call for `(Move{ 20 }` and vector is out of capacity, so it reallocates. It allocates new memory, move-constructs its elements (so, the `Move{10}`) into that new memory and then move-constructs the one you want to `push_back` (the `Move{20}`)

Comment: So it will actually call move constructor for each object every time vector is out of size or capacity?

Comment: Every time it's out of capacity. Most compilers will increase allocated memory by 1.5x or by 2x every reallocation. And as I mentioned, you can `reserve()` enough memory upfront to avoid reallocations.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, my head was spinning because I couldn’t understand what was happening.

Comment: @alkendev You should be printing the value of `this` in the constructors and destructors so that you know which object is being constructed / destructed.

Comment: While I realise you're asking about calls of constructors of your class, it would help if you provided code that does things with your vector.     The working of `std::vector`, and various operations on it (member function) are significant in answering your question (e.g. in determining when a move or a copy constructor is called).